# Jquery each function only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery function. It will only update the first row and then stops. Strangely though if i take out the line:

```
$("#prev_loan_approval_date").html("Not Yet Approved");
```

and replace it with an alert it fires off for each row. Is there any reason why this would be the case. Was thinking it mightnt return true on the next iteration because i changed the text value but this was for the previous row so the next row should still return true and change the value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loan_history_application > tbody  > tr').each(function() 
    {
        if ($("#prev_loan_approval_date").text() == "01/01/1900")
        {
            $("#prev_loan_approval_date").html("Not Yet Approved");
        };
    });
```

Comment: Can you also show the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tr has a child "#prev_loan_approval_date"?
If yes, you must write

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loan_history_application > tbody  > tr').each(function() 
    {
        if ($(this).find("#prev_loan_approval_date").text() == "01/01/1900")
        {
            $(this).find("#prev_loan_approval_date").html("Not Yet Approved");
        };
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that there shouldn't be multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: @kiko That did it for me. Thanks. Will mark it as correct in 4 minutes...when it lets me.

Comment: HTML ID's must be unique per page. This is letting you have the same ID exist in every row. It may appear to work due to browser quirk, but it is not right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be that you use an ID instead of class for `$("#prev_loan_approval_date").html("Not Yet Approved");` so it will only update the first row.

Change this to:

```
$(".prev_loan_approval_date").html("Not Yet Approved");
```

And make sure you also change ID to class in your HTML.

Comment: This doesn't search for that element per row

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple items with the same ID, it doesn't work. IDs should be unique. Change them to class and change in your code:

```
$(".prev_loan_approval_date").html("Not Yet Approved");
```

**Full Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loan_history_application > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".prev_loan_approval_date").text() == "01/01/1900")
            $(this).find(".prev_loan_approval_date").html("Not Yet Approved");
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't search for that element *per row*

Comment: The full code is in the question. If you want, I can update my answer with the full one.

Comment: @DalHundal Have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

> *Was thinking it mightnt return true on the next iteration because i changed the text value but this was for the previous row*

No, this *isn't* for the previous row. There's several things wrong here. Firstly the fact that you're using an ID for something that seems to occur more than once (ID's must be unique). You should use a class.

Secondly, where you're changing the text - you're *not* doing it just for that row. You're *always* doing it on *every* row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.loan_history_application > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    if ($(".prev_loan_approval_date", this).text() == "01/01/1900")
    {
        $(".prev_loan_approval_date",this).html("Not Yet Approved");
    };
});
```

And in your HTML change `id='prev_load_approval_date'` to `class='prev_loan_approval_date'`